# Android Graphs - how did these people make it?

Tags: android, api, graph, charts

I searched for API for graphs (also on this site), I tried some of them, but none gave me real solution with nice graphic. I can´t stop wondering, how these app made it. Can you advise me where I can learn this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.gsjavadev.android.systemmonitorlite

Answer (score 1):

You will soon find this RFI smothered under a thick blanket of suggestions for third party Android-customised chart tools and links to other SO questions asking the same thing, but you need not entertain them for very long...

Our preferred solution (which fits our design paradigm and UX requirements) is to use the Google Chart API. This is what many of the FX stock exchange apps use, it is built and maintained by Google and not an enthusiast - not to say non-corporate solutions are poor by any means but graphing isn't an area full of discovery and wonder, it just needs to be executed in a aesthetically pleasing and robust manner, Google achieve this.

There are two paths with the Google Chart API;

- Image charts for browsers without svg support (i.e. any browser before Honeycomb?), recently deprecated.
- JavaScript based wizzy soooper awesomeness version. Haven't used it myself but our app will move toward this in the near future. This is probably what these apps are using.

Its well documented, go have a play, the results are impressive for so little input on the developer side with the only catch being you need an internet connection and that you are sending information off to a server not under your control. Some data protection issues there...

Comment: Just came across this little chesnut too, http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/ - looks nice.

Comment: It sounds like you're not a great fan of Android charting libraries like AChartEngine :)

Comment: Battle scarred from incorrect tech decisions in the past! :) When a defacto approach becomes apparent I'm all ears.

Comment: I've just been re-reading about AChartEngine after my remark and noticed that you wrote the various canvas enhancements to make it possible. Is the project still alive and kicking? How do I find out the roadmap? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can we use Google Charts without an internet connection? My approach is to use HighCharts, which, IMHO, are a lot better looking than Google's, is backed by a corporation which sole purpose is to develop HighCharts, and you can embed the JS in your app so it works offline.

Comment: Unfortunately not, Google ask that you do not embed the JS libraries involved in their library. I agree HighCharts are better looking. I looked into using them but since my app is paid (throttling downloads if anything!) then I would need to pay a high price for a non-critical feature (the app is fully featured without the charts). I'm thinking of taking another look at the now more mature AChartEngine myself.